# Documents.Add.Content.Paste - error 4198 in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, paste

I have written application which copies all text from this [web page](http://biblehub.com/text/genesis/3-15.htm),

I check the content of the clipboard twice. First in the external program, which copied the webpage, then in Word when pasting the text from the clipboard and the error happens.

For any case, I have added timer to wait, but it is not neccessary because the text is in the clipboard - I am sure.

```
 Dim BufObj As MSForms.DataObject, BufTxt As String
 Set BufObj = New MSForms.DataObject
 BufObj.GetFromClipboard
 BufTxt = BufObj.GetText ' I added BufTxt to watch panel

 Dim tmpStart
 tmpStart = Timer
 Do
    DoEvents
 Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer

 Documents.Add.Content.Paste
```

On some page, it works and pasted the text. But on this one it does not. The debugger stopped on the line `Documents.Add.Content.Paste`

Do you have some idea how to fix the problem? I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247849/vba-error-4198-runtime-error-with-paste). where is one answer suggestion to remove links but I cannot find any code there how to do it.

**Edit:**

Code updated, but the error still happens. I found that when the debugger break, after I stop the macro, then I cannot paste the data from clipboard (ctrl+v). But the `BufTxt` contained text when I checked it in the debugger.

Comment: did you see this ?  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/84628eed-a242-42db-8dd9-19c40c10969f/word-2013-vba-runtime-error-4198?forum=worddev

Answer (score 0):

try this test code. it inserts text from a clipboard 100 times.

no paste function is used, so repagination should not affect it  (i am guessing)

```
Sub appendFromClip()

    Dim BufObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set BufObj = New MSForms.DataObject   ' clipboard object

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = Documents.Add(DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = doc.Range                   ' whole document

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 100                      ' test: repeat a bunch of text appends

        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd        ' collapse range into an insert point at end of document

        BufObj.GetFromClipboard
        rng = BufObj.GetText              ' note: rng becomes the range of the added text, so you have to collapse rng before adding more text

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested and it worked. But the problem is that I need the table to stay in the text because I use it to locate the content in the columns. Your code removed the table.

Comment: is the table in the clipboard?

Comment: Yes. It is table from the web page. Post edited. I found I cannot paste the data from clipboard even with ctrl+v when makro stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simple removing of the first command

```
Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
```

Have fixed the problem. I have had two windows opened when I have pasted the clipboard. After removing the program runs faster and error no happens.