# ActiveDocument.Bookmarks().Range.Paste gives 4198 runtime error in Mac VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, office-automation

When trying to paste a graph or table in a bookmark in Word it gives a 4198 runtime error on a Mac device. In Windows the macro runs fine. Moreover, a picture can be correctly inserted on the specific bookmark. However when trying to paste a graph a table, the runtime error occurs.

This part works as we want (paste the logo on the specific bookmark, resize and bring in front of text):

```
Set pic = oWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(' Logo').Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fNameAndPath)

pic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pic.Width = 75
    
Set Shp2 = oWord.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(1).ConvertToShape
Shp2.ZOrder msoBringInFrontOfText
```

The graph is correctly copied because I can manually paste it after the macro stops running on the error. The error occurs on when trying to paste the graph. A part of the code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oWord = GetObject(Class:=("Word.application"))
If Err Then
  Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:=("Word.application"))
End If
On Error GoTo 0
        
' Wait until the Word application is loaded
Do While oWord Is Nothing
   DoEvents
Loop
        
' Word application is loaded, make it visible
oWord.Visible = True

'Open wordDocument
oWord.Documents.Open wordDocument
        
Worksheets(Sheet).ChartObjects("chart").Copy
  
'Paste the graph at specific bookmark
oWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range.Paste
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What does *"doesn't work on a Mac device"* actually mean? [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: See if you have links in your Word document: [VBA Error 4198 "Runtime Error" With Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247849/vba-error-4198-runtime-error-with-paste).

Comment: @Peh Try to remove other bookmarks, however paste option still results in a 4198 runtime error. Also tried with a blank word document with the only link 'bookmark1' and still same error occurs. PastesSpecial does not help as well.

Comment: @Lieske I see this as well. Both applications hang, but eventually the error is displayed. The Range object is accessible (e.g. you can display the value of .Start), and once the Chart is in the clipboard a manual paste into the document works fine. SO IMO it is an error in Word Automation on Mac.(One of many, for example in this case if you make a reference to the Word application and use Dim oWord As Word.Application the routine will not escape the DoEvents loop.